# gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled under tmux?

Tags: tmux, git, gpg

I have found a strange error. It is OK when I commit using gpg with git under bash or zsh.

```
git commit -S -m "xxx"
```

However when I commit it under tmux, I got:

```
gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that your `GPG_TTY` variable is correct; add

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

to your shell startup scripts, including for non-login shells (your login shells are probably OK, but not non-login shells, which is why this fails in `tmux`).